# Get a random row from a database query in Kohana 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using the ORM module in Kohana 3 and instead of displaying the first row of a database result set, what query should I use in my code when I want to get a random row from a certain table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this (if using MySQL):

```
ORM::factory('some_model')->order_by(DB::expr('RAND()'))->find();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can issue the query directly, if you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 ORDER BY RAND();
```

Or with [Kohona Query Builder](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder):

```
$this->db->from('table')->select('*')->limit(1)->orderby(null, 'RAND()')->get();
```

Comment: If it is a much-used query I would even consider making it a proc since it requires no input.

Comment: Oops, forgot to say that I'm using ORM. How do we do that using ORM? :)

Comment: @Xeoncross: Yeah, that may be a good idea. @ed: AFAIK you don't, ORMs aren't meant for that kind of stuff.

Comment: your solution works, but only because second parametr in order_by instruction is not escaped or SQL-injection protected in other way (should be!). So "right" way to do this is thru Db:expr